# explode strings while missing certain elements

Tags: php, regex, arrays

Anyone got any idea on how to deal with explode to miss elements if there nesting inside something? Examples below.

So i have a data structure like so...

```
 {1,2,3,{4,2},5,6}
```

I am trying to convert that into a php array like so...

```
 array( 1, 2, 3, array( 4, 2 ), 5, 6);
```

Any ideas on how that might work? Some suggestions have been Regex or explode while monitoring a state machine? ( but i have no idea on how they work :S )

Comment: In PHP 5.4, that is an array literal, and will _just work_.

Comment: It also suspiciously looks like JSON to me.

Comment: `[1,2,3,[4,2],5,6]` is valid in PHP 5.4 http://codepad.viper-7.com/5t4K6A

Comment: I understand in this case that works, but what if they wasn't square and instead was something like {1,2,{3,2},4,5}

Comment: @MattPsyK Edit your question to reflect that.  It changes the question dramatically.

Comment: @Matt PsyK update your question  ...

Comment: Sorry didn't realise how close it was to json.

Comment: @MattPsyK Does the output structure change if you had something mixed like  `[1,2,{3,4},[5,6],7]` ?  If not, then the solution is to replace `{} or ()` with `[]` and still call json_decode() onit.

Comment: I was thinking more of a solution where you didnt know what the encapsulation would be, as in it would be random each time.

I know that may mean a back backend, but thats not something i can control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$string  =  "{1,2,{3,2},4,5}" ;
var_dump(__array($string));

$string  =  "[1,2,3,[4,2],5]" ;
var_dump(__array($string));

$string  =  "(1,2,(3,2),4,5)" ;
var_dump(__array($string,array("(",")")));

$string  =  "+1,2,+3,2-,4,5-" ;
var_dump(__array($string,array("+","-")));


function __array($string,$seperator = array("{","}"))
{
    $string  = str_replace($seperator, array("[","]"), $string);
    return json_decode($string);
}
```

Output

```
array
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => 
    array
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 2
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
```